# How to disable LazyVim replacing operators => with arrows and other syntax replacements

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I want to prevent LazyVim from replacing certain character combinations with these shorthand representations.
[image]

I'm still a little new to the vim/neovim ecosystem, but I've tried quite a few things and couldn't find any questions out there that mentioned what I was talking about.

- I've tried setting the conceal level to 0
- I've read through the lazyvim docs trying to find some mention of what is doing this but I cant seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Neovim or LazyVim.

It is a *font feature* called "ligature", which merges a common combination of characters used as an operator in programming languages to improve readability.

If you don't like them, you should disable them through the terminal settings - either by choosing a different font without ligature or disabling ligature support. *How* you do this depends on the terminal emulator you are using, so I cannot answer those details.